# Can't use getStaticProps and getServerSideProps together, is there another way to get client's user agent?

Tags: javascript, next.js

The website I am currently working on does not have a responsive design. Thus, the view I render depends on the client's user agent.  To do so, I need `getServerSideProps` to decide which view I should render. On the other hand, considering the website's needs, It's better if I used `getStaticProps` and revalidated it every 3 minutes. But, as you might know `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` can not coexist. Is there any other way to get user agent headers?
Here is my code:

**util.js**

```js
import * as Parser from "ua-parser-js";

export const isMobile = (req) => {
  let ua;
  if (req) {
    ua = Parser(req.headers["user-agent"] || "");
  } else {
    ua = new Parser().getResult();
  }
  return (
    ua?.device?.type === "mobile"
  );
};
```

**somepage.js**

```js
import { isMobile } from "util";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const SomePage = ({ isMobile }) => {
  return isMobile ? <View1 /> : <View2 />;
};

export default SomePage;

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  return {
    props: {
      isMobile: isMobile(req),
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You can't use both at the same time for a given page. You can either use `getServerSideProps` to server-side render the page with the user-agent information retrieved on the server; or use `getStaticProps` and handle the user-agent logic on the client-side. With `getStaticProps` there is no way to determine the user-agent on the server-side, the check would always have to happen on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can works in your case. Use middleware in Next.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

You can get User agent header by using middleware(like auth). You can also modify the request and respond directly.

By using middleware, i think you can benefit from getserversideProps and use getStaticprops in your page folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638467)

Comment: Oh i see i'll fix it later

Answer (score -2):

In your case , it's better to use `ISR` method , and it is implemented using `getStaticProps` with interval . when there is cached version of the page , its returned to user with `SSG` method , if cache does not exists or it's not valid , the paged is rendered with `SSR` method .

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
 
  return {
    props: {
    },

    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand your point. This is exactly what I'm trying to use in my app. But using `getStaticProps`, I won't be able to use `getServerSideProps` to detect the client's device. The fact that these two methods are mutually exclusive is my problem.

Comment: Actually you can't do that because in `getStaticProps` you dont have access to HTTP `req` & `res` objects and its independent from users request . You can implement your logic client side and also benefit from caching with ISR

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid. But I guess I have no other choice and need to handle ua on client. Thanks anyway.